# Hackerrank Movement Slots: Code OpOptimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

Im, trying to solve a hackerank problem, the problem is:

A light plastic ball is bounced on a stationary wheel situated horizontally on a table. There are *n* equal sized slots arranged radially around the centre of the wheel. Each slot ,*i*,is large enough to hold the ball, and has at its base a rubber sheet that can be activated to kick the ball in a clockwise direction around the wheel by a fixed distance *d*<sub>i</sub>(if *d*<sub>i</sub> is negative, then it is understood to be a kick in the counter-clockwise direction). So, if the ball lands in slot *i*, it will then bounce from slot *i* to the one |*d*<sub>i</sub>| slots away in the clockwise direction if *d*<sub>i</sub> > 0 and in the counter-clockwise direction if *d*<sub>i</sub> < 0. The activation mechanism at the base of each slot is pitched at an angle, so that *d*<sub>i</sub> is never 0.

If the ball is first dropped onto slot *a* , we want to know the slot that the ball lands in after bouncing *b* times. (The first bounce occurs at slot *a*, so if *b* = 0 , then the ball would remain at *a*).

I have a problem with that if b is too large my code will be slow as it uses a for loop, how can i reduce the size of b or make my code more efficient.

```
def final_slot(a, b, slots):
    current_slot = a
    for _ in range(b):
        current_slot = (current_slot + slots[current_slot]) % len(slots)
    return current_slot
```

Update

```
def find_last_bounce(jumps, queries):
n = len(jumps)
results = []

# Process queries and store results
for a, b in queries:
    # Initialize the current slot to the starting slot
    current_slot = a
    
    # Simulate the movement of the ball for b bounces
    for _ in range(b):
        # Determine the next slot based on the direction indicated by di
        current_slot = (current_slot + jumps[current_slot]) % n
    
    results.append(current_slot)

return results

if _name_ == '_main_':
   fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

   first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

   n = int(first_multiple_input[0])

   q = int(first_multiple_input[1])

   jumps = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

   queries = []

   for _ in range(q):
       queries.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

   results = find_last_bounce(jumps, queries)

   fptr.write('\n'.join(map(str, results)))
   fptr.write('\n')

   fptr.close()
```

This code is a little faster but it still cant take input for when jumps is 10<sup>12</sup>

Comment: Clearly it's not about optimizing the code to do the same thing faster. You need a different approach. If you think about running that sequence for a billion steps, are all those steps going to be equally interesting? Does the sequence of visited slots have some property you could work with?

Comment: You can *merge* steps. For exemple, you can write a table to apply 2 iterations based on the `current_slot` (I assume the number of slots is fixed for the function and `b` is big). Based on this, you can then write a twice faster code. But, hey, you can do this merging steps on already merged ones so to make the operation fourth times faster. Again and again, you can recursively compute larger steps. In the end, it should run in `O(log b)` time, but the pre-computation time should takes `O(len(slot) * log(b_max))` which is quite small I think compared to `O(b)`.

Comment: ok so i would do a recusion call like final_slot(a,b-5,slots) or something like that and end when b is 0.

Answer (score 0):

For large number of steps `b` the sequence is going to look like this: first the ball will visit some slots for `X` steps. Then the sequence of visited slots will start endlessly repeating after every `Y` steps.

The largest possible period is `Y=n` (e.g. each slot will bounce to the next one).

If you detect X and Y (detecting the intro and period length left as exercise to the reader), then

```
if b<=X, run the sequence for b steps as before

if b>X, run the sequence for X+(b-X)%Y steps to find the answer (to skip over all the repetitions)
```

now your iteration should always be at most `n` steps for the period detection and another `n` to find the answer.

Comment: let us say x is 1000
so if b>1000 i should do 
for _ range(1000+(b-1000)%len(slots):
 currentslot=(current_slot + slots[current_slot]) % len(slots)
?

Comment: @Geddez the repetition length as len(slots) doesn't seem right. Imagine 999 steps forward and one step back, that will have a 2-step repetition at the end. You have to actually measure X and Y for your input data.

Comment: You can measure it e.g. by running the sequence and keeping track at which step you visited each slot. When you visit one for the second time, you can already tell both the intro length (first visit) and the repetition length (second visit - first visit). (+-1, do not take too literally, test)